# ec2 port 80 remote desktop

Tags: amazon-ec2, port, remote-desktop

I changed the listening port of my EC2 instance to port 80 to circumvent firewall and rebooted the machine. I no longer am able to connect to the instance now.

Could someone tell me how I could change back the port to what it was without logging in? The problem may be because I have Apache installed on the machine that is also listening on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Login to the EC2 panel and from the left sidebar menu select "Security Groups". Select the group that your instance uses and remove port 80 and add ssh(if you have removed it).